# Calculating the Limit . $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\space \left[ \int_0^{1}\ [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy\right]^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, limits, definite-integrals

Find the value of  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\quad 
 \left[  \int_0^{1}\ [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy\right]^{1/x}\\ \quad where\space (a,b) \in \begin{align*}\
\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
$$
My approach : since it is of the form $ ( \rightarrow {1})^{\rightarrow\infty}$
so wrote it in the form of exponential i.e $e^ {(f(x)-1)(g(x))}\quad where,\ f(x)=\left[  \int_0^{1}\ [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy\right] \quad and\quad g(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ .
But was unable to solve from from here onwards .
Any help would be appreciated.!

Thanks !

Comment: Calculate the integral first, then the limit: did you try to find the integral?

Comment: nope, will try it now . Thanks.

Comment: Using the substitution $by+a(1-y)=t$ changes your integral to $$\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b t^x\, dt=\dfrac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)} $$

Comment: Can you proceed further after the evaluation of integral in my previous comment?

Comment: yes, Thankyou !

Answer (score 1):

By L'Hopital's Rule, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln\bigg\{\left[  \int_0^{1}\ [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy\right]^{1/x}\bigg\}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln\bigg\{\int_0^{1}\ [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy\bigg\}}{x}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\int_0^{1}\ [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy}\int_0^{1}\frac{d}{dx} [ by+a(1-y)]^{x}dy\bigg|_{x=0}\\
&=&\int_0^1(b-a)\ln[(b-a)y+a]dy\\
&=&\int_a^b\ln tdt\\
&=&b\ln b-a\ln a-(b-a).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: that's  $\lim_{x\to0}$  actually..not  $ \lim_{x\to\infty}$

Comment: Why? Tell me the reason please.

Comment: In the question , $\lim_{x\to0}$ is mentioned. U did it for  $ \lim_{x\to\infty}$

Comment: Sorry, I did not look at carefully. The answer is the same. Thanks.

Comment: No, the answer isn't the same..

Comment: I made a mistake before. I think this time it is ok.

Comment: I think your answer has got an extra factor of $(b-a) $.

Comment: The final answer after exponentiating should be $$\frac {(b^b/a^a) ^{1/(b-a)}}{e}$$